# how save data of login with Google in Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a project with firebase where I implement the authentication specifically with Google and it works very well but now I need to save the registration data in the database and this is where the problems come from, I'm following a material in this url https: / /angularfirebase.com/lessons/google-user-auth-with-firestore-custom-data/

And it generates the following error.

Message Error

[image]

It should be noted that I am using Angular 6.

Regards...

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead pot the actual code and text of the error message. Having these as text makes them searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual code and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
this.user$ = this.afAuth.user.pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
        if (user) {
          return this.afs
          .doc<UsuarioInterface>(`usuarios/${user.uid}`)
          .valueChanges();
        } else {
          return of(null);
        }
      })
    );
```

Then the observable `user$` will be null if the user is not signed in, otherwise is will have user's data.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the frustration. However you can also do the following 'tinkerings' to achieve similar goals:

Using EMAIL REG:

```
  import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
  import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
  import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

  @Injectable()
  export class yourAuthService {

   constructor(
   public afAuth: AngularFireAuth
    ){

     }
   .......
    ........
  ........

emailRegister(val){
return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(val.email, val.password)
  .then(() => {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      var userRef = firebase.firestore().collection("users/").doc(user.uid);
      userRef.set({name: name, email: value.email,   user: 'newUser.uid', adminEmail: '' })
      .then(function (){
      })

  })
})
}
```

That should do the trick and you will be on your merry way! Sweet and simple. You can use same approach for soc-media registration methods too :).  Yes, you can use that snippet with Angular-6. Hope it helps you have better insight and more options. Maybe someone will explain the different approaches better.